# Import keyword is not recognized by gulp throwing SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm, gulp

```
Failed to load external module babel-core/register
Failed to load external module babel/register
somelocation\gulpfile.babel.js:27
import fs from 'fs';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:192:16)
    at module.exports (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\node_modules\flagged-respawn\index.js:17:3)
```

I am getting this error while trying to run gulp after npm as described here: [deploy-appengine.md](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/deploy-appengine.md). How to fix it?

Comment: It looks like it can't find babel and babel-core. Do you have those on your node_modules directory?

Comment: some answers says, use require instead of import

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: as Luke Bennet points out correctly in a comment to this answer, it was indeed JavaScript - the [ES6 "import" syntax](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html). The issue is that this won't work out of the box in Node as yet.

---

You seem to be using the [python module import syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) in NodeJS. You should use the [NodeJS module require syntax](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/what-is-require).

Comment: The import syntax used was valid JavaScript rather than Python - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import. That said, this syntax is not supported by Node.js out of the box yet, a transpiler like babel is required (the lack of which was the cause of the issue here). Reverting back to CommonJS modules is one solution, but it is perfectly possible to use the newer import syntax with the right setup.